# Google tag manager - Show debug bar by default in environment?

Tags: google-tag-manager, environment

I wonder if it is possible to automatically show the GTM debug bar when loading GTM with a specific environment and/or other GTM variable?

I have set up a new environment in GTM to be used for dev/testing purposes. When setting up this environment there is a checkbox with the option to "Turn on debugging when previewing". I first thought that this did just this, but no debug bar appears by default even though I checked it and is loading GTM with the code that the environment applies. What does this do then?

I actually can get what I want, sort of, by adding the parameter `gtm_debug=x` to the implementation code, however this feels hacky maybe, and also causes the console to log a weird 400 error to GTM:s api domain, which doesn't feel so good...

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I've came across a similar (or maybe even the same) problem. I've wanted to enable the QA team to access/show the GTM debug toolbar (i.e. enable/disable it) on their behalf and without going into tag manager.

This is the solution I came up with:

```
https://www.googletagmanager.com/set_cookie?uiv2
&id=GTM-XXXXXXX
&gtm_debug=x
&gtm_auth=AUTH
&gtm_preview=env-0
&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F

(enable debug)
```

where "GTM-XXXXXXX" has to be replaced with your container ID and "url" is an optional parameter.

This URL sets the necessary cookies to switch GTM into debug mode and also provides a link to leave debug mode again ("Exit preview and debug mode").

```
https://www.googletagmanager.com/set_cookie?uiv2
&id=GTM-XXXXXXX
&gtm_auth=
&gtm_preview=
&gtm_debug=

(leave preview and debug mode, i.e. remove cookie)
```

The values for "gtm_auth" and "gtm_preview" are different per container/environment and you can find them via "Get Snippet" from the "Actions" menu of each environment on the "Environments" view ("Admin" -> "Environments"). You can also get them for the two default environments, i.e. "Live".

> When setting up this environment there is a checkbox with the option
> to "Turn on debugging when previewing". I first thought that this did
> just this, but no debug bar appears by default even though I checked
> it and is loading GTM with the code that the environment applies.
> What does this do then?

"Turn on debugging when previewing" is from the "Share preview" screen. On the "Environment Configuration" screen, it says "Enable Debugging by Default" and also [Google's documentation](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6311518?hl=en) suggests what you (and me) expect:

> Optional: Check Enable Debugging by Default if you need the environment to always use [preview mode](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107056).

But it doesn't work for me neither. :(

The preview & debug mode relies on 3rd party cookies (i.e. cookies on [www.googletagmanager.com](http://www.googletagmanager.com) and even if the checkbox is checked they are not set. The missing cookies are also the reason for the 400 error you were mentioning.